# Compiling legacy components in Next.js (Can't resolve 'react/jsx-dev-runtime', Global CSS cannot be imported)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I've just spun up a new Next.js project (React v 17.0.1). I am attempting to compile and import components from a legacy project. Seeing a few errors getting things to work:

1. `Module not found: Can't resolve 'react/jsx-dev-runtime'`. I have a hunch this may have something to do with the [new JSX compiler in React 17](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html).

   - This *can* be resolved by adding `/** @jsxRuntime classic */` to the top of the file, but i'd prefer to just turn on the classic compiler. Is this possible?
2. `Global CSS cannot be imported from files other than your Custom <App>`

   - This can be resolved by using modules, or importing in `pages/_app`. However, i'd like to turn this safety feature off, leaving the legacy components as is.

#### Questions:

1. How can I force Next.js to use the `classic` JSX compiler instead of the new `automatic` one
2. How do I turn off the safety "feature" forcing CSS to only be imported to `_app`?

Comment: First error shouldn't be a problem with next.js >= 9.5.3 (see https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/16603 and https://github.com/vercel/next.js/releases/tag/v9.5.3).
Global CSS can only be imported in the `_app` component, that is how next.js operates. You can import scoped CSS in single components as described here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#adding-component-level-css
I don't know if this is applicable for your case.

Comment: Oh, if you want to force next.js to use the classic JSX transform, you have to set up your custom babel config as described here: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/customizing-babel-config

Answer (score 1):

This was solved by downgrading the React dependency to 16 in package.json